# Remove spaces only before and after pipe

Tags: c#, .net, regex, replace, whitespace

I have the following string, which separates from the pipe "`|`".

```
string sample = "SVC1 | SVC2 | SVC3 | SVC1 ";
```

I need to remove whitespaces before and after the pipe. I wrote the following regex which works fine and removing extra space after the comma Ex: `SVC1 , SVC2 , SVC3 , SVC1`

```
var value = Regex.Replace(sample, " *, *", ",");
```

How can I change above regex to work with pipe?

Comment: Either you should use Trim() before creating the bad output or split and ignore the spaces :             string[] output = input.Split(new char[] { ' ', '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray();  You should not be using Regex when there are string methods that are much more efficient to do the task.

Answer (score 1):

`|` is a special char and means `or` in regex so it needs to be escaped: `\|`

```
string sample = "SVC1 | SVC2 | SVC3 | SVC1 ";
var value = Regex.Replace(sample, @" *\| *", "|");
```

Comment: I think this regex is a bit more elegant `(\s)?\|(\s)?`

Test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/Xa4hZZ/1)

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq,

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

string sample = "SVC1 | SVC2 | SVC3 | SVC1 ";
string result = sample
                  .Split('|')     //Split by pipe 
                  .Aggregate(string.Empty, (x, y) => x + y.Trim()+'|'); //Trim white spaces and concatenate with previous string 

    Console.WriteLine(result);  //Print result
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hCAGby)

Comment: Any specific reason for downvote? @Flydog57 My solution remove spaces **only** before and after pipe. If you are downvoter can you please provide your feeback for downvote

Answer (score 0):

```
string output = string.Join('|', sample.Split(new char[] { ' ', '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

Comment: That will split on all spaces, not just the ones on either side of the pipe.  The OP should have included at least one example of a sub-string that includes an embedded space, since his/her question was "Remove spaces **_only_** before and after pipe"